# How to simulate piano keys created by canvas element

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a piano from below example
[click functions through references variables on a canvas-possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330719/click-functions-through-references-variables-on-a-canvas-possible)

I am trying to simulate piano keys where I have an array of notes & then as per note it should show status of piano key as pressed for a particular time.

I have tried a simple test with delay function as shown below, but its not working,

```
function playnote(){
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();                 
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fa3';
    a = arrayWhites[notecounter ];
    ctx.rect(a[0], 0, whiteKeyWidth - 2, h - 1);
    ctx.fill();
    renderPiano(true).delay(300);  
    renderPiano(false); 
}
```

Comment: when you say 'its not working' could you describe the problem you're having a little more ? also where have you defined your `canvas` ?

Comment: Key remains pressed, but as per code after 3 seconds (renderPiano(true).delay(300);) it is expected that "renderPiano(false);" function should be called which will again show all piano keys in unpressed mode.

Comment: I suggest to refer code snippet from this example ":http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330719/click-functions-through-references-variables-on-a-canvas-possible" because I have used it as it is. you can see it in action in the example itself

Comment: `delay` i think is used for qued items,.. have you tried `setTimeout` ?

Comment: 'SetTimeout' calls same function with time interval, but I want to change state of key (color) in the same function with time difference. Typically I want to stop execution of code for some time & then continue again

Answer (score 0):

I got one solution

write one more function

```
 function stopplay()
 {
 renderPiano(false); 
 }
```

call them one after

```
setTimeout(function(){ playnote() }, 0000);
setTimeout(function(){ stopplay() }, 1000);
```

Key will pressed & released after one second.
You can manipulate piano keys as per array in playnote() function shown in the question and remove line "renderPiano(false);" & delay() from playnote()

```
function playnote(){
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();                 
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = '#fa3';
a = arrayWhites[notecounter ];
ctx.rect(a[0], 0, whiteKeyWidth - 2, h - 1);
ctx.fill();
renderPiano(true);  
//renderPiano(false); 
}
```